# Pop up contact form disappears when clicking the submit button

Tags: php, html, contacts, contact-form

The form is based on bootstrap here is the code:

When i try to validate the submition of the for using this very simple code.
Then the form just disappears.  Any insights guys would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks
New gal to coding.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 contact-form">
      <form id="contact" method="post" class="form" role="form">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 form-group">
            <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="FIRST NAME" type="text" required autofocus />
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 form-group">
            <input class="form-control" id="name" name="lastname" placeholder="LAST NAME" type="text" required
              autofocus />
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 form-group">
            <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="EMAIL" type="email" required />
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 form-group">
            <input class="form-control" id="name" name="phone" placeholder="PHONE" type="text" required autofocus />
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 form-group">
            <input class="form-control" id="name" name="address1" placeholder="ADDRESS 1" type="text" required
              autofocus />
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 form-group">
            <input class="form-control" id="name" name="address2" placeholder="ADDRESS 2" type="text" required
              autofocus />
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 form-group">
            <input class="form-control" id="name" name="city" placeholder="CITY" type="text" required autofocus />
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3 form-group">
            <input class="form-control" id="name" name="state" placeholder="STATE" type="text" required autofocus />
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3 form-group">
            <input class="form-control" id="name" name="zipcode" placeholder="ZIPCODE" type="text" required autofocus />
          </div>
          <h1 class="h1-contact">WHAT SERVICES ARE YOU INTERESTED IN?</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h3>SELECT ALL THAT APPLY:</h3>
            <label class="checkbtn">item 1
              <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="item5" value="item5">
              <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
            <label class="checkbtn"> item 2
              <input type="checkbox" name="item4" id="item4">
              <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
            <label class="checkbtn">item 3
              <input type="checkbox" name="item3" id="item3">
              <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
            <label class="checkbtn">item 4
              <input type="checkbox" name="item2" id="item2">
              <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
            <label class="checkbtn">item 5
              <input type="checkbox" name="example1">
              <span class="checkmark"></span>
```

Comment: Can you clarify how you're trying to do the validation? It looks like some of the code may be missing.

Comment: Thank you, for the reply. I am using PHP for validation.
<?php
if(submit){
echo "tested";
}
?>
and then the form just disapears.